# The Requirement for "Literal Type" in "constexpr" Functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, constant-expression, constexpr-function

Here is my code:

```cpp
class agg_t1{
    int x;      // private non-static data menber
};
class agg_t2{
    agg_t2(){}      // user-provided constructor
};
constexpr void ce1(agg_t1 arg){};       // OK
constexpr void ce2(agg_t2 arg){};       // ERROR:  parameter type 'agg_t2' is not a literal type
```

---

According to [dcl.constexpr](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3.2):

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements: ...
>
> - each of its parameter types shall be a **literal type**; ...

And [basic#types.general-10](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-10.5.2):

> A type is a literal type if it is: ...
>
> - it is either a closure type, an **aggregate type**, or ...

I understand the reason why `agg_t2` is not a literal type is that, it violates the rule [dcl.init.aggr#1.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1.1):

> An aggregate is an array or a class  with ...
>
> - no user-declared or inherited constructors  ...

and I think `agg_t1` may not be a literal type because it violates the rule [dcl.init.aggr#1.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1.2) too:

> An aggregate is an array or a class  with ...
>
> - no private or protected direct non-static data members   ...

However... the [compiler result](https://godbolt.org/z/dE8jcvz3r) tells me I was wrong about the assumption for `agg_t1`.

##### My question is:

If `agg_t1`'s private data member `x` makes it non-aggregate type ,then why the `agg_t1` type is permitted in `constexpr` function definition of `ce1`?

Comment: There were words that come after "aggregate type" in the definition of what types are literal types. Those words might be important.

Comment: Your argument is that neither `agg_t1` nor `agg_t2` are aggregates, despite their cleverly-chosen names. You have yet to eliminate the other possibilities by which they might be literal types (closure type and whatever you cut off after the "or" -- as with the "or" operator, proving that one operand to `||` is false does not make the entire expression false.)

Comment: @NicolBolas Can I have those words that you mentioned? I read it agagin but I haven't found any information useful for myself

Comment: "... or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template (possibly inherited ...) that is not a copy or move constructor,"

Comment: That part after or: "... or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template". It  so happens that an implicitly-declared default constructor for `agg_t1` is `constexpr`, per [**\[class.default.ctor\]/4**](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#4)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik According to the [test](https://godbolt.org/z/zYvPj93fP), which gives *"...because the implicit declaration is not 'constexpr'"*. Due to this error, I don't think that implicitly-declared default constructor is "consexpr". Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: @JiříBaum So should I consider it as the situation with " or has at least one constexpr constructor "? But I've tried to declare that "implicit default constructor" as *constexpr*, But failed with errors which mentioned on the previous comment.

Comment: Add `-std=c++20` switch, then your test [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Yvozv9xe4).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! So can I consider it as a bug for the versions prior to CPP20?

Comment: I must admit I'm not sure why your original example compiles even with C++17. I understand why `constexpr` test fails with C++17 - C++17 requires that `constexpr` constructor initialize all non-static members; C++20 removes this requirement. But indeed, `agg_t1` doesn't appear to be a literal type under C++17 rules, so not clear why `ce1` is accepted there.

Answer (score 0):

> If `agg_t1`'s private data member `x` makes it non-aggregate type, then why the `agg_t1` type is permitted in `constexpr` function definition of `ce1`?

---

#### C++20

`agg_t1` is indeed not an aggregate class due to its private data member, however whilst aggregateness *can* be one of the *sufficient* requirements for class type to be a literal type, it is not a *necessary* one. Note the *or* condition of [[basic.types.general]/10.5.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types.general#10.5.2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> - [...]
> - a possibly cv-qualified class type **that has all of the following properties**:
>
>   - [...]
>   - it is **either** a closure type ([expr.prim.lambda.closure]), an aggregate type ([dcl.init.aggr]), **or has at least one constexpr
>     constructor** or constructor template (possibly inherited
>     ([namespace.udecl]) from a base class) that is not a copy or move
>     constructor, [...]

As per [[class.default.ctor]4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.default.ctor#4.sentence-4):

> [...] If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the
> requirements of a constexpr constructor ([dcl.constexpr]), **the
> implicitly-defined default constructor is constexpr** [...]

and [[dcl.constexpr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#3) and [[dcl.constexpr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#4):

> /3 The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following
> requirements:
>
> - [...]
> - if the function is a constructor or destructor, its class shall not have any virtual base classes; [...]
>
> /4 The definition of a constexpr constructor whose function-body is
> not = delete shall additionally satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - for a non-delegating constructor, **every constructor selected to initialize non-static data members** and base class subobjects **shall
>   be a constexpr constructor**;
> - [...]

the implicitly-defined default constructor of `agg_t1` is `constexpr`, and thus [basic.types.general]/10.5.2 does not disqualify `agg_t1` from being a literal type in C++20.

---

#### C++17

In C++17 the implicitly-defined default constructor of `agg_t1` is not `constexpr`, as it violates [[dcl.constexpr]/4.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.constexpr#4.5):

> The definition of a constexpr constructor shall satisfy the following
> constraints:
>
> - [...]
>
> In addition, either its function-body shall be = delete, or it shall
> satisfy the following constraints:
>
> - [...]
> - /4.5 every non-variant non-static data member and base class sub-object **shall be initialized** ([class.base.init]);

And indeed, whilst the following is rejected by both Clang and GCC for `-std=c++17`:

```
class A {
    constexpr A() = default;  // error: cannot be constexpr
private:
    int x;
};
```

the following is accepted:

```
// OK: B is a literal type.
class B {
    constexpr B() = default;  // OK
private:
    int x{};
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the patient explanations. While being convinced by most of it, I doubt this: *"In C++17... agg_t1 is not constexpr...it violates..."*. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/8K9fsdsrW)(11,14,17,20) shows that `ce1` accepts the type `agg_t1`, which has only one private data member, meaning that `agg_t1` must be a valid *LiteralType*. Since we all agree that `agg_t1` is not an "aggregate", according to the requirements(basic.types.general#10.5) of *LiteralType*, then if its implicitly-defined constructor is still not "constexpr", what else it could be that makes it become a valid *LiteralType*?

Comment: @absuu Afaict this seems like a standard defect. And indeed, open issue [CWG 1360](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1360) writes: _"According to 11.4.5 [class.ctor] paragraph 6, a defaulted default constructor is constexpr if the corresponding user-written constructor would satisfy the constexpr requirements. However, the requirements apply to the definition of a constructor, and a defaulted constructor is defined only if it is odr-used, leaving it indeterminate at declaration time whether the defaulted constructor is constexpr or not."._